# Split CSV file by rows in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with 1,609 rows and I would like to split the CSV file into 1,609 separate files with 1 row per file. I managed the write the code to do this correctly, but I cannot seem to figure out how to have the header row (row 0) show in each of the 1,609 files.

While this isn't a huge deal, I would like to save each file by the name that is in Column AH of each CSV file as well.

Thank you for any help and support.

I am using the following code which is working correctly. I am only trying to figure out how to include the header row (row 0) and to change the file name of each CSV that is being written.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

split_source_file = ('all_groups.csv')

pd_dataframe = pd.read_csv(split_source_file, header=0)
number_of_rows = len(pd_dataframe.index) + 1

print(f"{number_of_rows}")

min_rows = ("1 : ")
max_rows = ("1 : ")

file_increment = 1
skip_rows = 1

number_of_rows_perfile = random.randint(min_rows, max_rows)

while True:

    if number_of_rows_perfile <= 0:
        break
df = pd.read_csv(split_source_file, header=None, nrows = number_of_rows_perfile,skiprows = skip_rows)

    split_target_file = f"{split_source_file[:-4]}_{file_increment}.csv"
 
    df.to_csv(split_target_file, index=False, header=False, mode='a', chunksize=number_of_rows_perfile)

    file_increment += 1

    skip_rows += number_of_rows_perfile


    if skip_rows >= number_of_rows:
        number_of_rows_perfile = number_of_rows - skip_rows
    else:
        number_of_rows_perfile = random.randint(min_rows, max_rows)
```

Comment: why you need pandas? read the file line by line and save each line to a file

Comment: @balderman I am not sure. This is just how I was taught. It seems to be working...

Answer (score 0):

you have a very strange task, why would you need to split the csv into 1 line files?

anyway, i suggest you use pathlib.Path for path manipulation, it's much nicer than strings. it is also not clear why you'd use pandas, if you only want to split file.
here is how one would split file without pandas:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def split_file(src_file: Path):
    dst_dir = src_file.parent
    fname = src_file.stem
    
    with open(src_file, "rt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    header = lines[0]
    
    for i in range(1, len(lines)):
        dst_file = dst_dir / f"{fname}_{i}.csv"
        with open(dst_file, "wt") as f:
            f.write(header)
            f.write(lines[i])

split_file(Path("tmp/mytable.csv"))
```

and here is how you can save DataFrame row-by-row

```
import pandas as pd

def save_df_line_by_line(dst_dir: Path, fname: str, df: pd.DataFrame):
    for row_no in range(len(df)):
        row = df.iloc[row_no:row_no+1] # this way it's a pd.DataFrame, not pd.Series
        dst_file = dst_dir / f"{fname}_{row_no+1}.csv"
        # if you want name from "AH" column: 
        # dst_file=dst_dir/f"{row['AH'].iloc[0]}.csv"
        row.to_csv(dst_file)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2], 'c': [3, 3, 3]})
row = save_df_line_by_line(Path("tmp"), "mytable", df)
```

Comment: thank you for this. I am getting the following error after the first set: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "tmp/mytable.csv". Should this be the name of my CSV file that I am pulling data from?

Comment: @ScottMeyer-Kukan yes, you should paste the path to your file there. 
it does seem a bit like you don't fully comprehend what's going on in the code, maybe you should read a book on python?

Comment: @DaniilZuev, if you want to show how to do this without Pandas, please show how to use Python’s CSV module. You don’t know for sure if the CSV has multiline values, which will break when just splitting by lines of text. Always use a good, proven CSV parser.

Comment: I agree that I am not fully comfortable with Python coding as this is not something I do on a regular basis. However, I am tasking with moving a large amount of data from one system to another and this is what I need to do. I've had a basic education of Python coding and can get by with easy functions, but much of this is above my head.

Comment: @ScottMeyer-Kukan maybe splitting CSV line-by-line is not the best idea then. you should try some file splitting programs, that split files into chunks of equal size and reassemble them back, i'm sure there is a handful of free ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think, given what you said about your experience with Python, that you can accomplish what you need and understand what's going on using Python's csv module.

I mocked up this simple CSV, named input.csv, to make a simple example of what you aim to do:

```
| Alice   | Red            |
| Bob     | Periwinkle     |
| Charlie | Sea green      |
```

Let's see how to write a (fairly) simple script to create three CSV files for Alice, Bob, and Charlie.

The csv module provides a basic reader that iterates over rows from the input CSV, one row at a time.  The following:

1. opens the input CSV named input.csv for reading, and sets newline='' (because that's what you need to do when using the csv module)
2. reads the entire CSV into the list, `data`

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)
```

Looking at `data`, we see a list of lists of strings:

```py
[
    ["Alice",   "Red"       ],
    ["Bob",     "Periwinkle"],
    ["Charlie", "Sea green" ],
]
```

For this example I'll create a file based on name, the first column (which is actually the "zero-th column" in list-index speak).  I loop over the each item in data, which represents a whole row, and use that name (`row[0]`) to construct an output filename.  Then, open the filename for writing, creating a writer, and write the current row:

```py
for row in data:
    fname = f"output-{row[0]}.csv"

    with open(fname, "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

and that creates three files:

```
output-Alice.csv        output-Bob.csv          output-Charlie.csv
```

Alice's CSV looks like:

```
Alice,Red
```